# How do I fix this regex? (How to get overlapping matches that share a word?)

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I'm trying to structure text using regular expressions - splitting and grouping all managers in the following example format:

```
General MANAGER
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
Nursing MANAGER
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
Financial MANAGER
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
Human Resource MANAGER
John Doe (Acting)
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
Marketing OFFICER
John Doe
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
Pharmacy MANAGER
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
Technical Services MANAGER
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
```

I've tried

```
(?<FOUND>^.*?(manager|officer)+.*?)(manager|officer)+
```

expecting it to group items like this:

```
General Manager
John Doe
(123) 456 7890
abcdefg@netcare.co.za
```

but it's not quite working.  Can any regexpert tell me how to fix it?

I'm using http://regexhero.net/tester/ for testing with options:
CultureInvariant, ExplicitCapture, IgnoreCase, Multiline, SingleLine

Comment: Is your format consistent? i.e. do you have always 4 lines per contact? Position/name/email/phonenumber?

Comment: What's the input to the regex?

Comment: Thanks, but not quite right still. The only consistent thing is that manager\officer heads a section to separate.  There's not necessarily anything else - like the same number of lines, or an email.  I need the expression to be: from the beginning of a line containing MANAGER to the end of the line just before the next line containing MANAGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

```
 ^(?<Title>.*(?:Manager|Officer)).*\n(?<Name>.*)(?:\n(?!.*(?:Manager|Officer))(?<Detail>.*))+$
```

See: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=1ac1bd9f-be0a-4bea-ac01-cc32a6605ae7

Retrieve values using

```
Match.Groups["Name"].Value
Match.Groups["Title"].Value
Match.Groups["Detail"].Captures[1..n].Value
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!  I see it's the negative lookahead that is the key.  Out of interest, is it possible to have an explicit capture group in the expression (i.e. (?<name>))?  Because I had trouble trying to keep lookaheads in the expression for the .* parts, but keep them out of the capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the last character in the file is a newline, you might want to try a positive lookahead assertion at the *end* of your regular expression. Find all blocks that start with manager or officer and are preceded by either a manager or officer line or EOF.

```
(^.*?(manager|officer)(.*?$)*?)(?=(^.*?(manager|officer))|\Z)
```

However, if there really is little other structure than the fact that block data is ended when a new block starts, I personally would prefer the following old-fashioned approach:

```
# WARNING: pseudocode 
managers = []
for line in file:
    if 'manager' in line or 'officer' in line: 
        manager = new Manager(line)
        managers.append(manager)
    else:
        manager.set_data(line)
```

Comment: As long as it's OK to latch onto the `@` in the e-mail, this clever trick should work. I am not certain that it's OK, though, in case an internal e-mail is specified.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite right still. The only consistent thing is that manager\officer heads a section to separate. There's not necessarily anything else - like the same number of lines, or an email. I need the expression to be: from the beginning of a line containing MANAGER to the end of the line just before the next line containing MANAGER